# Reshaping R columns with Incremental custom header names

Tags: python, r, statistics

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, Min, Max, Average. The dataframe contains 7000 rows.

```
| Min | Max | Average |
| 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.3     |
| 1.0 | 2.0 | 1.5     |
| 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.6     |
| 1.0 | 7.0 | 1.9     |
```

And I want

```
| Min1 | Max1 | Average1 | Min2 | Max2 | Average2 |
| 1.2  | 1.4  | 1.3      | 1.0  | 2.0  | 1.5      |
| 1.2  | 1.4  | 1.6      | 1.0  | 7.0  | 1.9      |
```

Notice how the headers have been change to indicate first obervation and second observation.

I have looked at the other answers on reshaping, none of the other answers show how the new columns should be renamed to include a number.

Comment: Do you want a python or `r` solution?

Comment: @akrun R solution please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, we can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create a grouping variable using 'grp' so that every two rows have a unique index ('grp'), using `dcast` we convert the 'long' to 'wide' format by using the formula method.  The `rowid(grp)` gives a sequence for each grp.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := gl(.N, 2, .N)]
res <- dcast(df1, grp~rowid(grp), value.var = c("Min", "Max", "Average"), 
                            sep="")[, grp := NULL][]
```

If needed, we can `order` the columns as showed in the OP's post.

```
res[, order(as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", names(res)))), with =FALSE]
#   Min1 Max1 Average1 Min2 Max2 Average2
#1:  1.2  1.4      1.3    1    2      1.5
#2:  1.2  1.4      1.6    1    7      1.9
```

---

We can also do this with `base R`, by splitting the dataset by creating a sequence vector and `cbind` the output

```
do.call(cbind, split(df1,  (seq_len(nrow(df1))-1) %%2 + 1))
```

Or we can subset alternating rows with logical index (that recycles to the last row) and use `data.frame` to concat them.

```
data.frame(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE),], df1[c(FALSE, TRUE),])
#  Min Max Average Min.1 Max.1 Average.1
#1 1.2 1.4     1.3     1     2       1.5
#3 1.2 1.4     1.6     1     7       1.9
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Could you edit the response to explain what setDT(df1)[, grp := gl(.N, 2, .N)] and grp~rowid(grp) are actually doing?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Could you edit the response to explain what setDT(df1)[, grp := gl(.N, 2, .N)] and grp~rowid(grp) are actually doing?

Comment: is there a simpler way to do this using reshape package? Or could you explain some of the code above please?

Comment: @edb500 I added some explanation.

Comment: @ebd500 Added 2 more options.  Hope it helps